# MySQL ORDER BY two DESC in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have 2 MYSQL tables, **firma** and **rach**

- firma table:

```
id_fir  | nazwa | opis  | nr_konta  | logo
-------------------------------------------------
0   | abc   | abc   | 123       | img/abc.png
1   | qwerty| qwert | 123       | img/qwerty.png
```

- rach table:

```
id_rach | id_fir    | data_termin   | data_platnosc | kwota
----------------------------------------------------------------
0   | 1     | 2013-09-30    | null      | 123
1   | 0     | 2013-09-30    | 2013-09-17    | 123
2   | 0     | 2013-09-26    | 2013-09-21    | 321
3   | 1     | 2013-09-27    | null      | 333
```

My sql query:

```
SELECT r.`id_rach` , f.`nazwa` , f.`opis` , r.`kwota` , r.`data_termin` , r.`data_platnosc`
FROM rach r
INNER JOIN firma f
USING ( id_fir )
ORDER BY `data_platnosc` IS NULL asc, `data_termin` desc
```

I done so far:

```
id_rach | nazwa | opis  | kwota | data_termin   | data_platnosc
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   | abc   | abc   | 123   | 2013-09-30    | 2013-09-17
2   | abc   | abc   | 321   | 2013-09-26    | 2013-09-21
0   | qwerty| qwerty| 123   | 2013-09-30    | null  
3   | qwerty| qwerty| 333   | 2013-09-27    | null
```

I would like to get the result:

First data_platnosc is null and data_termin order desc

Then other data_termin order desc

```
id_rach | nazwa | opis  | kwota | data_termin   | data_platnosc
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0   | qwerty| qwerty| 123   | 2013-09-30    | null  
3   | qwerty| qwerty| 333   | 2013-09-27    | null  
1   | abc   | abc   | 123   | 2013-09-30    | 2013-09-17
2   | abc   | abc   | 321   | 2013-09-26    | 2013-09-21
```

and this solution?

I would like to get the result:

First data_platnosc is null and data_termin order asc

Then other data_termin is not null order desc

```
id_rach | nazwa | opis  | kwota | data_termin   | data_platnosc
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3   | qwerty| qwerty| 333   | 2013-09-27    | null    
0   | qwerty| qwerty| 123   | 2013-09-30    | null  
1   | abc   | abc   | 123   | 2013-09-30    | 2013-09-17
2   | abc   | abc   | 321   | 2013-09-26    | 2013-09-21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `order by` is almost correct:

```
ORDER BY `data_platnosc` IS NULL desc, `data_termin` desc
```

If you want the `NULL` values first, then use `desc` for the first element of the `order by`.  `IS NULL` returns `1` when true, and you want that first.

Or, you could phrase is with `IS NOT NULL`:

```
ORDER BY `data_platnosc` IS NOT NULL asc, `data_termin` desc
```

For this:

> First data_platnosc is null and data_termin order asc.  Then other data_termin is not null order desc

Use a `case` statement:

```
ORDER BY `data_platnosc` IS NULL desc,
         (case when `data_platnosc` IS NULL then `data_termin` end) asc,
         data_termin desc
```

Comment: and when it comes to what I add to post?